# CodeIgniter Active Record; Merge two queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my first query, I am looping through all records that have a `status` of `open`, and `channel_id` of `23`, getting the column `field_id_299`. The field `field_id_299` is the `entry_id` for another `channel`.

The second query, then uses this `field_id_299` AS `entry_id`, getting the column `field_id_36`.

Is it possible to do all of this in one query?

```
$query = ee()->db->select('cd.field_id_299')
             ->from('exp_channel_titles AS ct')
             ->join('exp_channel_data AS cd', 'ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id', 'left')
             ->where('ct.status', 'open')
             ->where('ct.channel_id', '23')                  
             ->get();

$query = ee()->db->select('field_id_36')
             ->from('exp_channel_data')
             ->where('entry_id', $entry_id)
             ->get();
```

Comment: I am not sure.. but can you run below mysql query and confirm me that this is your desired result or not. `select field_id_36
from exp_channel_data
where entry_id in (    
select cd.field_id_299 
from exp_channel_titles ct
left join exp_channel_data cd on ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id
where ct.status='open' and channel_id = 23);`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$query = ee()->db->select('cd1.field_id_36')
             ->from('exp_channel_titles AS ct')
             ->join('exp_channel_data AS cd', 'ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id', 'left')
             ->join('exp_channel_data AS cd1', 'cd.field_id_299 = cd1.entry_id', 'left')
             ->where('ct.status', 'open')
             ->where('ct.channel_id', '23')                  
             ->get();
```